# Can't access elements of an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I'm still quite new to Angular and JavaScript so apologies if this is an obvious mistake.

I have this code that selects 2 text files, then puts them into a single array.

```
$scope.textArray = [];
$scope.textUpload = function(event){
    var files = event.target.files;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = $scope.textIsLoaded; 
                reader.readAsText(file);
        };
};
$scope.textIsLoaded = function(e){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.textArray.push(e.target.result);
    });
```

This displays an array like:

> ["160 591 114 229","186 699 132 272"]

When I access the array through the HTML both elements of the array are displayed and I can use split, length, etc. But if I access the array through script I can only access and change the first element. If I try to access the second element through `textArray[1]` nothing will show up, if I add `textArray[1].split(' ')` it says that it cant read property of undefined.

I have tried using join and slice in the script to alter the array or create a new array, but they are unable to access the element as well. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Edit:
When I use

`$scope.arrayOne = $scope.textArray[0].split(' ')`

It works fine and outputs the correct thing, but when I use

`$scope.arrayOne = $scope.textArray[1].split(' ')`

It doesn't output anything.

Edit2: Found another question with the same problem and managed to fix it by adding

```
$scope.$watch('textArray', function(){
```

In front of

```
$scope.arrayOne = $scope.textArray[1].split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and split the

```
$scope.textArray[1].split(' ');
```

That should work. Make sure you pass the `$scope` as parameter to the method that is trying to split the `textArray`.

This is a working example:

```
 <div ng-controller="ResultSplit">
   {{result}}
 </div>
```

And the javascript:

```
 function ResultSplit($scope) {
   $scope.textArray = ["1223 2233", "3344 555 6666"];
   $scope.result = $scope.textArray[1].split(' ');
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but it just says Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

Comment: I tried it like this
$scope.arrayOne = $scope.textArray[1].split(' ');

Comment: Can you show me the method in which you tried this? It would not work just if you don't pass the $scope in the method you write this line.

Comment: I have been using it here: $scope.textIsLoaded = function(e){
But I also tried using it in the main controller, when i put it in the controller it caused all of my code to break down.

Comment: @Matt You can try the above and check if that works, it works in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/6092/#&togetherjs=7Boye5DV8t